# Simple HTML DOM get meta tag's special attribute's value

Tags: html, dom, attributes

I want to use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ on my project

How can I get content's value?

```
<html>
<head>.....</head>
<body>
    <meta itemprop="keywords" content="a,b,c,d">
<body>
<html>
```

Im trying below but it is not working

```
echo  $html->find('meta[itemprop=keywords]')[0]["attr"]["content"]
```

expected output should be: a,b,c,d

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $html->find('meta[itemprop=keywords]', 0)->content;
```

by official manual: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the meta tags and loop through them:

```
foreach($html->find('meta') as $meta){
}
```

Then you can check if the meta tag has an attribute called 'itemprop', and if the itemprop has a value of 'keywords':

```
if($meta->getAttribute('itemprop') && $meta->getAttribute('itemprop') == 'keywords'){
    }
```

Then you can just output the content attribute:

```
echo $meta->getAttribute('content');
```

Complete code:

```
foreach($html->find('meta') as $meta){
    if($meta->getAttribute('itemprop') && $meta->getAttribute('itemprop') == 'keywords'){
        echo $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
```